# "Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator" this keeps popping up every time i try to run my code

Tags: r, statistics, rstudio, bioinformatics

I have some raw data from 52 patients, and I have formatted the raw data to have the Entrez Gene ID on the first column, and the ID for each patient in the next 52 columns.  I set the working directory, where to access the raw data file, the fdr and the fold_change. My code then ran like this:

```
setwd(working_dir)

rawdata = read.table(rawdata_file, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = NULL, sep = "\t")

dim(rawdata)
head(rawdata)
str(rawdata)

quant <- apply(rawdata, 1, quantile, 0.75)
******
keep <- which((quant >=2) ==1)
rawdata <- rawdata[keep,]
dim(rawdata)
```

But once I got to `quant <- apply(rawdata, 1, quantile, 0.75)`, the following error pops up:

> Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I am pretty new to R, so I would appreciate any help with my code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means you are applying a mathematical function onto something thats not numeric. You need to do it without your first column.

Something that looks like your data

```
rawdata = data.frame(ID=paste("ID",1:100),matrix(runif(100*52),ncol=52))
colnames(rawdata)[2:53] = paste("patient",1:52)
head(rawdata)

    ID patient 1 patient 2 patient 3 patient 4 patient 5 patient 6 patient 7
1 ID 1 0.7147973 0.2104862 0.7846074 0.3394161 0.8544912 0.2300092 0.4161791
2 ID 2 0.3030303 0.8720105 0.2767706 0.9455382 0.4907579 0.7021114 0.5986684
   patient 8 patient 9 patient 10   patient 11 patient 12 patient 13 patient 14
1 0.02630086 0.7088419  0.3951715 0.3238016008  0.9807989  0.2146602  0.8076201
2 0.21665396 0.2540735  0.6269772 0.0009961955  0.8641968  0.8014775  0.6408617
  patient 15 patient 16 patient 17 patient 18 patient 19 patient 20 patient 21
1 0.03178842 0.70620702  0.7614409  0.5516146 0.05971609  0.3702968 0.90079876
2 0.27334311 0.03484481  0.4803889  0.4838688 0.52853695  0.5037140 0.03115113
  patient 22 patient 23 patient 24 patient 25 patient 26 patient 27 patient 28
1  0.8249698  0.2767941  0.5306544  0.9688781  0.5995393  0.3427149  0.2921866
2  0.2949440  0.2681442  0.8809229  0.3602453  0.3122242  0.9680564  0.6417741
  patient 29 patient 30 patient 31 patient 32 patient 33 patient 34  patient 35
1  0.1217374  0.5721696  0.8807429 0.09401768  0.3994375  0.5825191 0.073809400
2  0.5270218  0.1007655  0.5142553 0.17269346  0.4051577  0.1968952 0.007899745
  patient 36 patient 37 patient 38 patient 39 patient 40 patient 41 patient 42
1  0.2451399  0.8466774  0.4001425  0.8081921  0.6977565  0.3230159  0.4933366
2  0.1184844  0.8383270  0.9715824  0.9436642  0.1118531  0.5044923  0.2659268
  patient 43 patient 44 patient 45 patient 46 patient 47 patient 48 patient 49
1  0.5872126  0.8283301  0.4381552  0.5863271 0.06969155  0.1848659 0.91026236
2  0.9452248  0.6210323  0.5066544  0.5289093 0.71125154  0.6000685 0.05133945
  patient 50 patient 51 patient 52
1  0.8214441  0.2272655  0.5048466
2  0.7853656  0.1296575  0.7862940
```

Gives the same error

```
apply(rawdata, 1, quantile, 0.75)
Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Do:

```
data.frame(ID=rawdata$ID,value=apply(rawdata[,-1],1,quantile,0.75))
```

To select on the dataframe based on quantile, you need to always work with the numeric column value:

```
quant <- data.frame(
ID=rawdata$GeneSymbol,
value=apply(rawdata[,-1],1,quantile,0.75)
) 
keep <- quant[which(quant$value >= 2),]
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for helping me with the code. It worked! However, when i continued with my process, all the data in my data frame then became "NA". Do you mind taking a look: 
quant <- data.frame(ID=rawdata$GeneSymbol,value=apply(rawdata[,-1],1,quantile,0.75))
#
keep <- which((quant >= 2) ==1)
#
After this code, then the following error popped up: 
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors
#
rawdata <- rawdata[keep,]
#
dim(rawdata)
After this code, i looked at the rawdata again, and all my data has become "NA" instead of the numbers I got.

Comment: Hi @jacquelynesun, i edited my answer above, and it would work for you. If there are anymore issues related to your other processes, i would suggest posting them as another question.

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.